# What do you get if you publish a C# console app project using Publish As Azure WebObject from VisualStudio 2013?

Tags: azure, azure-webapps

I have written a simple socket server as console app project and socket client as console app project in C#. I deploy the socket server project to Azure cloud using Publish As Azure WebObject from VisualStudio 2013. But I cannot connect my client app on premise to the server on cloud.

If Publish As Azure WebObject is not the right way, what would be the correct way to deploy other than to cloud VM?

Comment: Please clarify your subject heading: What do you mean by "What do you get..."?  Thank you.

Comment: I assume that, after you published your application as WebObject, it could simply run as service on Azure Web Page. Am I right?